# How to compare if the time between two dates is between two other dates?

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I want to compare if the time between $begin and $end is between starttime and endtime.

My table has the following layout:

**id - name - starttime(in datetime) - endtime (in datetime)**

Example entry in the table:

**32** - **test** - **25.03.2019-5:00pm** - **25.03.2019-6:15pm**

Example:

$begin: 4:45pm 
$end: 6:30pm

This example should give me the entry with the id 32 because the timeblock between $begin and $end is already in my table!

```
SELECT * FROM timetable WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME($begin) BETWEEN starttime AND endtime OR FROM_UNIXTIME($end) BETWEEN starttime AND endtime
```

Comment: What does this query return? Please share some output.

Comment: The query should return the entry where the time is between $begin and $end... In my example, it have to return the example entry in the table (id 32)

Comment: I understood that.. asking about the result when you run this query you wrote..what did it return?

Comment: Are you saving datetime in this format `25.03.2019-5:00pm`?

Comment: No, I save it in the normal datetime format like in SQL but I am from Germany and there is an other date format as in America or India... The result of the current query is null because he only checks if the $begin is between starttime and endtime OR $end is between starttime and endtime BUT he should also check IF the time BETWEEN $begin and $end IS between starttime and endtime!

Comment: Ok, try the answer posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said in the comments, you have `begin` and `end` values in `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` so here is a query to check get the desired output:

**Try this:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM timetable 
WHERE $begin >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`starttime`)
AND $end <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`endtime`) 
AND $begin < $end
```

**How it works:**

```
$begin >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`starttime`)
```

It checks if begin time is greater than or equal to starttime saved in the database.

```
$end <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`endtime`)
```

It checks if end time is less than or equal to endtime saved in the database.

```
$begin < $end
```

It checks if endtime is greater than start time.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hey, I've tried this but it doesn't work! In my table, there was an entry like starttime = "2019-03-26 11:00:00" AND endtime ="2019-03-26 12:15:00" AND my $begin was "1553593500" and my $end = "1553598000" and it returns me nothing but it should have returned the abovementioned entry

Comment: @itranger I have updated the answer. Please try it now and make sure you pass UNIX_TIMESTAMP values as you mentioned in your comments as begin and end values.